# Finding max, min, and closest root of two dimensional data

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some data that is two dimensional (traditional (x, y) format) as so:

```
var = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}
```

I would like to search through that large list and find the maximum and minimum y values and return the ordered pair.  Something like:

```
min[var]->{x2, y2} //read "->" as returns {the minimum ordered pair}
max[var]->{x3, y3} //read "->" as returns {the maximum ordered pair}
```

Finally I know the data has a "root".  A plot of the points cross the x-axis.  I would like to find the closest few (maybe 3 or 4) points to zero.  Questions similar to this have been posted but I cannot figure out how to adapt those solutions to my needs

[previous work 1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13557/local-max-min-of-mathematica-data-sets)

[previous work 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/mathematica-finding-min-max-in-list)

Comment: You overlooked [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/find-zero-crossing-in-a-list), which may be more useful to you.

Comment: How about `var[[Ordering[var[[All, 2]]][[1]]]]` and `var[[Ordering[var[[All, 2]]][[-1]]]]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own function with which to sort a list. For instance:

```
tab=Table[{Random[] - 0.5, Random[] - 0.5}, {n, 20}]
sorted=Sort[tab,#2[[1]]^2>#1[[1]]^2&]
```

This will give you a list where the elements with `x` closest to `0` will be first. You can take the number of desired values from this list.

For the element with the highest and lowest y element, you can use @Sjoerd C. de Vries' example in the comment, or you can define your own ordering:

```
sortedminmaxy=Sort[tab,#2[[2]]>#1[[2]]&]
```

and this will have the data ordered by the y value. You can then take the first and last elements as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pattern I described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25101/12), define

```
MaxBy[list_, fun_] := list[[First@Ordering[fun /@ list, -1]]]
MinBy[list_, fun_] := list[[First@Ordering[fun /@ list, 1]]]
```

then do

```
MinBy[data, Last] (* smallest y *)
MaxBy[data, Last] (* largest y *)
MinBy[data, Composition[Abs, Last] ] (* closest to 0 *)
```