# making Max and Min work columnwise like Median

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some data and the rows are grouped according to `astGroupsPos` (the `astGroupsPos` are just rows from `dat` ordered and grouped in some fashion):

```
dat = {{0.148`, 0.014`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.035`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.735`, 0.065`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.077`, 0.`, 
    0.019`, 0.`, 0.012`, 0.`, 0.263`, 0.612`, 0.018`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.063`, 0.`, 0.017`, 0.`, 0.027`, 
    0.`, 0.216`, 0.66`, 0.016`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`}, {0.231`, 0.075`, 0.009`, 0.`, 0.009`, 0.002`, 0.266`, 
    0.404`, 0.006`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.17099999999999999`, 0.098`, 0.01`, 0.`, 0.006`, 0.002`, 
    0.335`, 0.374`, 0.007`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.151`, 0.083`, 0.012`, 0.`, 0.018`, 0.`, 0.503`, 0.222`, 
    0.011`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.173`, 
    0.056`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.018`, 0.`, 0.491`, 0.25`, 0.014`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.131`, 0.069`, 0.012`, 0.`, 
    0.019`, 0.`, 0.479`, 0.267`, 0.023`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
     0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.15100000000000002`, 0.045`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.014`, 
    0.`, 0.268`, 0.508`, 0.013`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`}, {0.14600000000000002`, 0.039`, 0.011`, 0.`, 0.023`, 
    0.`, 0.434`, 0.324`, 0.022`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`}, {0.059`, 0.`, 0.02`, 0.`, 0.023`, 0.`, 0.202`, 0.643`, 
    0.053`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.11499999999999999`, 0.049`, 0.01`, 0.008`, 0.03`, 0.`, 
    0.233`, 0.541`, 0.02`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.111`, 0.014`, 0.017`, 0.`, 0.022`, 0.`, 0.208`, 0.613`, 
    0.015`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.078`, 
    0.038`, 0.011`, 0.022`, 0.054`, 0.`, 0.299`, 0.475`, 0.024`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.098`, 0.034`, 0.04`, 
    0.019`, 0.016`, 0.`, 0.371`, 0.407`, 0.016`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.131`, 0.067`, 0.03`, 0.`, 0.029`, 
    0.`, 0.29`, 0.428`, 0.019`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`}, {0.152`, 0.049`, 0.01`, 0.037`, 0.031`, 0.`, 0.277`, 
    0.417`, 0.019`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.123`, 0.065`, 0.039`, 0.093`, 0.009`, 0.`, 0.167`, 
    0.438`, 0.019`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.128`, 0.086`, 0.034`, 0.`, 0.016`, 0.`, 0.102`, 0.577`, 
    0.003`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.097`, 
    0.142`, 0.011`, 0.`, 0.017`, 0.002`, 0.244`, 0.428`, 0.022`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.131`, 0.048`, 0.028`, 
    0.`, 0.015`, 0.`, 0.212`, 0.533`, 0.025`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
     0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.106`, 0.232`, 0.034`, 0.`, 0.022`, 0.`, 
    0.304`, 0.259`, 0.04`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.116`, 0.085`, 0.042`, 0.`, 0.016`, 0.004`, 0.15`, 0.567`,
     0.013`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.033`, 
    0.032`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.022`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.828`, 0.084`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
     0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.122`, 0.104`, 0.009`, 0.`, 
    0.014`, 0.`, 0.216`, 0.517`, 0.018`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
     0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.087`, 0.007`, 0.012`, 0.`, 0.01`, 0.`, 0.242`,
     0.624`, 0.017`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.145`, 0.021`, 0.008`, 0.`, 0.039`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.745`, 
    0.052`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.119`, 
    0.029`, 0.017`, 0.`, 0.116`, 0.`, 0.114`, 0.551`, 0.045`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.052`, 0.022`, 0.057`, 
    0.`, 0.093`, 0.`, 0.095`, 0.579`, 0.1`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.265`, 0.316`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.047`, 0.036`, 
    0.`, 0.153`, 0.02`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.185`}, {0.376`, 0.368`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.032`, 0.062`, 0.`, 0.088`, 
    0.07`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.078`}, {0.437`, 
    0.283`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.034`, 0.071`, 0.`, 0.071`, 0.04`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.108`}, {0.401`, 0.33`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.071`, 0.027`, 0.`, 0.114`, 0.062`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
     0.`, 0.`, 0.058`}, {0.267`, 0.346`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.044`, 0.036`, 
    0.`, 0.168`, 0.062`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.14`}, {0.122`, 0.084`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.061`, 0.05`, 0.`, 0.6`, 
    0.109`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.34`, 
    0.19`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.059`, 0.002`, 0.`, 0.222`, 
    0.034999999999999996`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.133`}, {0.367`, 0.359`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.053`, 0.056`, 0.`, 0.015`, 
    0.039`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.141`}, {0.369`, 
    0.301`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.035`, 0.042`, 0.`, 0.013`, 0.062`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.24`}, {0.816`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,
     0.002`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.003`, 0.009`, 0.111`, 0.059`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.116`, 0.`, 0.011`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.585`, 
    0.228`, 0.004`, 0.`, 0.005`, 0.022`, 0.029`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
    0.`}, {0.079`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.603`, 0.083`, 0.`, 
    0.006`, 0.`, 0.085`, 0.144`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}, {0.072`, 0.`, 
    0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.715`, 0.097`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.045`, 
    0.`, 0.021`, 0.05`, 0.`, 0.`}};
astGroupsPos = {{41}, {1}, {42}, {2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
    40}, {26}, {27, 28}, {29}, {30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36}, {37, 
    38}, {39}};
```

I can then group the data accordingly by:

```
(data[[#]] & /@ astGroupsPos)
```

So that I get median of each group (grouped rows) like:

```
(Median /@ (data[[#]] & /@ astGroupsPos))
```

I would like to do the same for `Max` and `Min` but the problem is that they flatten the array first. Is there any nice way to do it without loops? To be more explicit, from:

```
(data[[#]] & /@ astGroupsPos)[[4]]
```

the maxima are an array `{Max[{0.077,0.063}],Max[{0.,0.}],Max[{0.019,0.017}],...` and so on. I found a related post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/mathematica-finding-min-max-in-list) but this structure seems a bit more complicated

Comment: `Transpose[Max /@ Transpose[data]]` should yield a columnwise maximum.

Comment: @J.M. This does not work due to the more complicated structure of the data, I do not want to apply the `Max` to `data` but rather to `(data[[#]] & /@ astGroupsPos)` which cannot be actually transposed.

Comment: Do you want what J.M. said, just mapped over your groupings?  `Max /@ Transpose@# & /@ (data[[#]] & /@ astGroupsPos)`

Comment: Yes, that does the job, thank you. Can you put it as the answer?

Comment: Another way to do @wxffles's generalization: `(Map[Max]@*Transpose) /@ (data[[#]] & /@ astGroupsPos)`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way not mentioned in the comments, using [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) to do a ragged transpose as shown in the "Applications" section of the documentation.

```
Map[
 Max,
 Flatten[
  dat[[#]] & /@ astGroupsPos,
  {{1}, {3}, {2}}],
 {2}]
```

`Max` may be replaced by `Min`, `Median` or other function.

Comment: Anytime anyone uses the ragged transpose application of `Flatten`, it's an automatic +1.