# Apply multiple functions to same list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'd like to get the Min, Max, Median, Mean, etc. for the same list.  For now I'm doing the following:

```
y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
Map[{Max[#] , Min[#] , Median[#], Mean[#]} &, y, {0}]
```

It seems like there should be a better way, not that this is awful. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You are looking for `Through`: `Through[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}[y]]`.

Comment: A more restricted case of this question: [(3127)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3127/121).  More advanced questions possibly of interest: [(3858)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3858/121), [(11298)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/121)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Also,

```
y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

#[y] & /@ {Max, Min, Median, Mean}

(*  {7, 1, 4, 4}  *)
```

EDIT: comparing the timings:

```
n = 100000;

Do[Through[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}[y]], n] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.548089, Null}  *)

Do[#[y] & /@ {Max, Min, Median, Mean}, n] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.709574, Null}  *)
```

`Through` is more efficient, at least in this case.

Comment: I use this more often than `Through`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard any reasons, or just personal preference?

Comment: It never occurred to me that I could do that with map.  I never put the # in place of a function.  In retrospect I don't know why.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP  I use `Map` for so much else that it is very familiar, whereas `Through` still takes a moment of thought.  More importantly this works with held arguments, e.g. `#[2 + 2] & /@ {Hold, HoldForm, Defer, MakeBoxes}`.  And as nearly everyone knows I like terse coding and this is a few keystrokes shorter.

Comment: @Mr.W, ahh, how right you are, `&` has the attribute `HoldAll`. Convenient. Sometimes, of course, the opposite behavior may be desired.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP That's also a good point, e.g. `#[y] & /@ {Max, Min, Mean, Hold}` returns `Hold[y]` which *might* not be intended.  If evaluation is needed however it is easy, e.g. `# @@ {y} & /@ {Max, Min, Mean, Hold}`, and that is faster to change than rewriting to use `Through` would be, at least for me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard was, hä? Your last two examples return exactly the same output. I was referring to the difference of `Through[{Hold}[2 + 2]] -> {Hold[4]}` and `#[2 + 2] & /@ {Hold} -> {Hold[2+2]}`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I meant using the definition of `y` in Bob's answer.  More explicitly:  `#[2 + 2] & /@ {Hold}` versus `# @@ {2 + 2} & /@ {Hold}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, right, didn't realize that. Yes, we're talking about the same thing. But when optimizing code, I become really pedantic about an `Apply` here, and a `Through` there and so on, there it starts to count. Much like a debate you had once with Leonid about the most efficient form of the vanishing function.

Answer (score 34):

You can use [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html).

```
Through[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}[y]]

(* {7, 1, 4, 4} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've always had trouble getting the syntax of `Through` correct, since to me it seems more natural if it were instead `Through[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}][y]`

Comment: @murray You can use `Prefix` if it feels more natural: `Through@{Max, Min, Median, Mean}[y]`

Comment: Thanks! - I had tried through, but I used it wrong.  I tried to map or apply it.

Answer (score 21):

`Query` offers a reasonable syntax for this case:

```
y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

y // Query[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}]
(* {7, 1, 4, 4} *)
```

`Query` has the nice feature that we can apply such lists of functions at deeper levels without too much additional thought:

```
ys = {{1, 2, 6}, {4, 5, 9}, {10, 20, 60}};

ys // Query[All, {Max, Min, Median, Mean}]
(* {{6, 1, 2, 3}, {9, 4, 5, 6}, {60, 10, 20, 30}} *)
```

Comment: I did not realize `Query` could be used like that! +1 of course.  However it is not a general replacement for `Through` as the output is different, e.g. `"x" // Query[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}]` returns `{"x", "x", Missing["Indeterminate"], Missing["Indeterminate"]}`, and it is much slower than `Through` or `Map`, undoubtely related to [(56609)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56609/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your points are absolutely valid, but as usual you and I have different pain thresholds when labelling something as "much slower" :D  Using `Normal @ Query[...]` will eliminate both the semantic differences and the performance differences since the query will then be compiled down to a wafer-thin wrapper over `Through` (the canonical answer).  But I find myself using `Query` as-is with increasing frequency these days because its one-stop-shopping syntactic convenience usually overshadows the other considerations (for me, YMMV).

Answer (score 15):

I prefer:

```
{Max[#], Min[#], Median[#], Mean[#]} & @ y
```

Clean, simple, and elegant.

Answer (score 13):

[murray](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/148/murray) wrote:

> I've always had trouble getting the syntax of `Through` correct, since to me it seems more natural if it were instead `Through[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}][y]`

```
each[x : _[__]][arg__] := Through[ x @ arg ]

foo // each[bar[a, b, c]]

   (* out:   bar[a[foo], b[foo], c[foo]]   *)

Sequence[foo, bar] // each[{a, b, c}]

   (* out:   {a[foo, bar], b[foo, bar], c[foo, bar]}   *)
```

I rather like that idea.  Thanks, murray.

Comments below Bob Hanlon's answer remind me one thing this lacks as written is the ability to work with held arguments, which `#[y] & /@ {f1, f2, . . .}` has by nature.  If I am going to actually use this abstraction I will need to address that.  One possibility:

```
ClearAll[each]

each[x : _[__]] := Function[, Through @ Unevaluated @ x[##], HoldAll]
```

Now:

```
2 + 2 // each[{Hold, HoldForm, Defer, MakeBoxes}]

   (* out:   {Hold[2 + 2], 2 + 2, 2 + 2, RowBox[{2, +, 2}]}  *)
```

*Update:* also notably this case which is a bit harder to get with `Map`:

```
2 + 2 // each[ Hold[foo, bar, baz] ]

   (* out:   Hold[foo[2 + 2], bar[2 + 2], baz[2 + 2]]   *)
```

Comment: I still find the `(* ...*)` output convention much clearer.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I honored your opinion in this answer but I cannot promise that I will change my habit.   We'll see.

Answer (score 4):

And (so far), no one has suggested the *right* solution.

If you have a bundle of operations that you want to reuse, define a function.

```
stats[x_List]:= {Max[#] , Min[#] , Median[#], Mean[#]}& [x]
...

y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
stats[y]
(* {7, 1, 4, 4} *)
```

Comment: Why not `stats[x_List] := #[y] & /@ {Max, Min, Median, Mean}`, especially if you want to extend the list of stats?

Comment: @garej:  Habit of mind:  morphisms go to the left of the objects they act on.  (If I were an adherent to certain European algebraist schools, I'd feel the other way about it.)

Comment: Why not just `stats[x_List] := {Max[x], Min[x], Median[x], Mean[x]}` ?

Comment: @PaulCommentary : Habit of mind:  If expression `x` has side effects or if expression `x` takes significant resources to compute, repeatedly evaluating it is foolish.  To make it very clear what is guarded against, contrast `Clear[stats];
stats[x_] := {Max[#], Min[#], Median[#], Mean[#]} &[Activate[x]]; stats[y = 3; Inactive[Table[y++, {3}]]]` with `Clear[stats];
stats[x_] := {Max[Activate[x]], Min[Activate[x]], Median[Activate[x]], Mean[Activate[x]]}; 
stats[y = 3; Inactive[Table[y++, {3}]]]`.

Comment: Good answer @Er

Answer (score 4):

As of 2022 we have at our disposal the resource function called [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) that can do that. This is a development thanks to @Sjoerd Smit.

It was first suggested [**`here`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157305/function-addition-declaring-function-as-the-total-of-a-list-of-functions/277661#277661). In the comment section under the answer @Sjoerd Smit gives motivation for its development and subsequent use for those interested. It was further used [**`in this thread`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256096/perform-apply-to-a-sum-of-objects/278692#278692).

The way it works for the example at hand is the following:

```
ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{Max, Min, Median, Mean}]@{1, 2, 
  3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

> [image: l]

Answer (score 2):

As of version 14.0, we can also use `Comap`:

```
y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

Comap[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}, y]
(* {7, 1, 4, 4} *)

Comap[{Max, Min, Median, Mean}]@y
(* {7, 1, 4, 4} *)
```

[image]

Comment: This new function is so slow, e.g. `funlist=Array[f,10^5];
Comap[funlist,x];//RepeatedTiming
Comap[funlist]@x;//RepeatedTiming
Through[funlist[x]];//RepeatedTiming
Query[funlist]@x;//RepeatedTiming
Map[x,funlist];//RepeatedTiming`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Table` and `Operate`:

```
y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
funcs = {Max, Min, Median, Mean};

Table[Operate[funcs[[i]] &, {y}], {i, Length@funcs}]

(*{7, 1, 4, 4}*)
```