# Precision and replace all

Tags: replacement, precision-and-accuracy

I have a list of functions that I want to apply to a same argument. What I did is something like

```
{f[x],g[x],h[x]}/. x->N[10^6,300]
```

One of the functions is `Precision`. Clearly when I make the replace the precision is said to be infinity, because the argument is evaluated first. I tried some code with `Hold` to try that the argument would not be evaluated but it didnt work, by example

```
Precision[x]/. x->Hold@N[10^6,300]
```

Then my question is: how I can apply the same argument to a list of functions such that the argument remains completely unevaluated, such that functions like `Precision` works properly?

EDIT: I find an answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107721/apply-multiple-functions-to-same-list) but I want to know if its possible to do the same with the command `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: you are holding a wrong thing: `ReleaseHold[Hold@Precision[x] /. x -> N[10^6, 300]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `Inactive`

```
Inactive[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}] /. x -> N[10^6, 300] // Activate
```

Answer (score 2):

I think something like the following does what you want:

```
pInfo=Through @* {Precision, Accuracy, RealExponent};
```

Then:

```
pInfo[N[10^6, 100]]
```

> {100., 94., 6.}

Another idea is:

```
Function[x, {Precision[x], Accuracy[x], RealExponent[x]}] @ N[10^6, 100]
```

> {100., 94., 6.}